# how to speed up large xml file read/write operations

Tags: c#, xml, parallel-processing

I have a windows form application that currently does the following:

1) point to a directory and do 2) for all the xml files in there (usually max of 25 files ranging from 10mb to !5gb! - uncommon but possible)

2) xml read/write to alter some of the existing xml attributes (currently I use a single background worker for that)

3) write the altered xml attributes directly to a NEW file in a different dir

the little app works fine but it takes far tooo long to finish (about 20min depending on the net gb size)
what I casually tried is start the main rw method in a Parallel.ForEach() but it blocked itself out unsurprisingly and exited

my idea would be to parallelize the read/write process by starting it on all ~25 files at the same time is this wise? how can I do it (TPL?) without locking myself out?

PS: I have quite a powerful desktop pc, with 1TB samsung pro ssd, 16gb of ram, and intel core i7

Comment: Im surprised it locked itself out!

Comment: Are you sure that using an XML database wouldn't be a better solution?

Comment: I took your comment to heart and looked into xml dbs, I have no prior knowledge of these dbs so it may be an option...

Answer (score 1):

You can have a ThreadPool for this approach

You Can have a pool for a size of 20 files 
Because you have core i7 , you should use **TaskFactory.StartNew**
In this case , you should encapsulate the code for processing on file in the a sample class like XMLProcessor
then with use of TaskFactory.StartNew you can use multithreading for xml processsing

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for data parallelism via PLINQ + asynchronous lambdas.

I recently needed to process data from a zip archive that itself contained 5,200 zip archives which then each contained one or more data files in XML or CSV format. In total, between 40-60 GB of data when decompressed and read into memory.

The algorithm browses through this data, makes decisions based on what it finds in conjunction with supplied predicates, and finally writes the selections to disk as 1.0-1.5 GB files. Using an async PLINQ pattern with 32 processors, the average run time for each output file was 4.23 minutes.

After implementing the straightforward solution with async PLINQ, I spent some time trying to improve the running time by digging down into the TPL and TPL Dataflow libraries. In the end, attempting to beat async PLINQ proved to be a fun but ultimately fruitless exercise for my needs. The performance margins from the more "optimized" solutions were not worth the added complexity.

Below is an example of the async PLINQ pattern. The initial collection is an array of file paths.

In the first step, each file path is asynchronously read into memory and parsed, the file name is cached as a root-level attribute, and streamed to the next function.

In the last step, each `XElement` is asynchronously written to a new file.

I recommend that you play around with the lambda that reads the files. In my case, I found that reading via an async lambda gave me better throughput while decompressing files in memory.

However, for simple XML documents, you may be better off replacing the first async lambda with a method call to `XElement.Load(string file)` and letting PLINQ read as needed.

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace AsyncPlinqExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Limit parallelism here if needed 
            int degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

            string resultDirectory = "[result directory path here]";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("[directory with files here]");

            files.AsParallel()
                 .WithDegreeOfParallelism(degreeOfParallelism)
                 .Select(
                     async x =>
                     {
                         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(x))
                         {
                             XElement root = XElement.Parse(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());

                             root.SetAttributeValue("filePath", Path.GetFileName(x));

                             return root;
                         }
                     })
                 .Select(x => x.Result)
                 .Select(
                     x =>
                     {
                         // Perform other manipulations here

                         return x;
                     })
                 .Select(
                     async x =>
                     {
                         string resultPath = 
                             Path.Combine(
                                 resultDirectory,
                                 (string) x.Attribute("fileName"));

                         await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{DateTime.Now}: Starting {(string) x.Attribute("fileName")}.");

                         using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(resultPath))
                         {
                             await writer.WriteAsync(x.ToString());
                         }

                         await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{DateTime.Now}: Comleted {(string)x.Attribute("fileName")}.");
                     });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience with that topic, I couldn't get back to this so far but I will be able to next week, hopefully I can incorporate some of the suggestions and will report back asap